# import "django.shortcuts" could not be resolved from sauce Pylance(reportMissingModuleSoucre)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[![import "django.shortcuts" could not be resolved from sauce Pylance(reportMissingModuleSoucre)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def get_home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

i didnt try anything,i need some help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[add the extra path virtual env - Django installed/lib/sitepackages to workspace of visual studio code in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvTQB.png)
refer this img - [image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have selected the correct python interpreter (shortcuts "Ctrl+shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter") which you have installed the packages you want to import.

Or you can reinstall the packages under the python interpreter which you have selected in the VSCode.